# How do i get results for a search criteria that links to another table?

Tags: sql, oracle

I am trying to list all book titles given that they have the same authors who wrote the book 'Database principles'. I am not sure on how to link the author who wrote the book to the book title from the table Book and Author. How do i do this?

[image]

Comment: There should be an FK (foreign key) in the `BOOK` table referring to the `author`  table first in order to link them together

Comment: Is this a data modelling question or a SQL question? If a book can have many authors and `written_by` represents a table, that affects the answer.

Answer (score 0):

*Assuming that `BOOK` table has a column `AID` that is an FK pointing to `AUTHORID` of the `AUTHOR` table.*

There are many ways of doing so.

**Inner Query**

```
SELECT B.* FROM BOOK B  WHERE B.AID IN (SELECT AID FROM BOOK WHERE TITLE LIKE '%?%');
```

**Joines**

```
SELECT B1.* FROM BOOK B1  , BOOK B2 WHERE B1.AID = B2.AID AND B2.TITLE LIKE '%?%';
```

**Left outer join**

```
SELECT B1.* FROM BOOK B1 LEFT OUTER JOIN  BOOK B2 ON B1.AID = B2.AID WHERE B2.TITLE LIKE '%?%';
```